# Finding resources about about developing mobile app with CodeName One

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, mobile, codenameone

I developed lots of Java project since one year and now I try to develop mobile application with using Codename One in Eclipse. But i couldnt find totally beneficial resources about Codename One. I read Codeame One developers guide pdf document and watch some videos such as 'Hello Word with Codename One' but still i don't understand totally and i can just add buttons or labels on screeen but not more. Could ou please help me ? maybe give advice and some resources? 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned there are the PDF/JavaDoc listed here: http://www.codenameone.com/getting-started.html

The community forum listed here: http://www.codenameone.com/discussion-forum.html

The how do I video tutorials: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html

And There is also a full online course which is free for pro users here: http://udemy.com/codenameone101/

You also have a [Docs & Demos zip](http://www.codenameone.com/download.html) which contains a few example projects such as the Kitchen Sink (for handcoded applications) and quite a few other demos.

There are some community blogs such as [this](http://www.sjhannah.com/blog/) & [this](http://gadgets.coolman.ca/) (and quite a few others). If you have specific questions on how to achieve anything we also answer questions on the codenameone tag right here.

One of the main issues isn't the lack of information, but rather the fact that there is so much that its hard to find the right piece of information to get started. Assuming you are using the GUI builder I suggest the following How Do I videos to get started:

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-basic-hello-world-application--send-it-to-my-device-using-eclipse.html

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---positioning-components-using-layout-managers.html

http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html